# Point clouds in blender

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hi all i work with point clouds in blender, I was wondering if anybody has developed a tool that can mask/clip or hide parts of the point cloud from view, so i am able to work on small sections of point cloud without the need to cut areas out to model?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need an add-on for what you want to do, there are a lot of tools for viewing efficiency.

1. Hide the selection, <kbd>H</kbd> key, undo <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. View only the selected objects, <kbd>/</kbd> key, undo <kbd>/</kbd> (toggle)
3. Crop the view to a border, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and define a border left click + drag, undo <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Perhaps the third is what is suitable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to say yes there is, because this would be a nice feature,
but I don't know of any plugins that do this yet.

I'd also like to say you can just color a region then pop it over to another layer,
but it's not quite that easy...  So here's what you wanna do:

Create a copy of your point-cloud, then add a cube, sphere,
or other suitable object to block out a region.

Use a *Boolean* modifier set to **Intersect** on one copy,
and a *Boolean* modifier set to **Difference** on the other.

Turn off the view for the region you aren't using,
or move it to another layer for the time being.

When everything looks decent, you can use a *Boolean* modifier
set to **Union** to join your entire cloud together again.

Answer (score 0):

The free Point Cloud Visualizer plugin for Blender allows you to edit point clouds in this way - to crop them in 3D space:

https://github.com/uhlik/bpy#point-cloud-visualizer-for-blender-280